# string input in linked list [C]

Tags: c, string, list, input, fgets

I am just learning about linked lists. I wrote a little programm for myself practising the mechanism about linked lists. This is my first attempt trying to do a small pokedex (without actually saving anything). So I am trying to setup the input correctly. Currently everything works fine, no errors and I can execute it.

The problem is the 2nd time of inputing the pokemon name it does not read in any data, instead it skips reading in and goes directly to the scanf function, why is that the case?

```
void addPokemon(void){

    pokemonPtr firstPtr;
    pokemonPtr thisPokemon;
    firstPtr = NULL;

    firstPtr =(pokemon *) malloc(sizeof(pokemon));
    firstPtr->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

    printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
    fgets(firstPtr->name, POKEMON_LENGTH, stdin);
```

The problem is right here, this fgets is not really being executed, so basically it does not prompt the user to enter the string.

```
    printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf("%d",&firstPtr->number);

    firstPtr->next =(pokemon *) malloc(sizeof(pokemon));

    thisPokemon = firstPtr->next;

    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10){

        thisPokemon->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

        printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
        fgets(thisPokemon->name, POKEMON_LENGTH, stdin);
        printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
        scanf("%d",&thisPokemon->number);

        thisPokemon->next =(pokemon *) malloc (sizeof(pokemon));
        thisPokemon = thisPokemon->next;

        i++;

    }
```

Comment: write `getchar();` (for consume newline) after `scanf("%d",&firstPtr->number);`

Comment: I am not quite sure if this really helps, because it prompts me to enter something, but the problem is still existing.

I will edit in the main post where the problem exactly is.

Comment: try `scanf("%d%*c", &firstPtr->number);` instead of `scanf("%d",&firstPtr->number);`

Comment: Is `POKEMON_LENGTH` fixed for all Pokémon?

Comment: well I wanted to introduce a string limit, because I read a lot that it is good to do so for security reason. So I defined POKEMON_LENGTH to be only some characters long (maybe 15 I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets stops reading when a newline character is read. In your example, stdin already has a '\n' in it so fgets takes it and is done. This is because scanf doesn't read the newline character you get when you enter the number, leaving it in stdin.

Two solutions:

Instead of fgets, use `scanf("%s", name);`. This works because `%s` will ignore white space and newlines before the string it takes.

User getchar() to read the newline.

Comment: Awesome!
Well I was using scanf before, but somehow I always got warnings considering the string. Okay I guess I need to use char *name in the struct that this really works.

But I dont understand the thing with getchar()

Comment: Note, scanf will only work with 1 word Pokemon names... but all Pokemon names are one word I'm like 99% sure of

Comment: You got some good Pokemon knowledge there :)

What would I need to change to make two or more words possible?

Comment: To account for more than one word use `scanf("%[^\n]s",stringname)`

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies stdin is a stream of sorts. When you enter the number, it and a '\n' is sent to stdin. scanf will only consume the number leaving '\n' in stdin. getchar simply then consumes the newline.

Comment: guys!, thx for your help. I love this site, this is great!

@ezPaint One last question, how should this getchar() look like when it is implemented? I added it to the code and it just made me input twice instead of consuming the "\n"

Comment: @CherubimAnand use `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", stringname)` instead of. or `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", stringname)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is lot of times, the scanning statements are scanning `\n` character returning from previous scanning statements... you can avoid it many ways but all of those ways ultimately consume the `\n` character

some of the ways are:

- `scanf(" ");` *this space consumes the* `\n` *character*
- `getch();` *similarly*

  I've used the first in my below code.

---

**Note** : Always ensure to enter `name` of the Pokemon below specified `POKEMON_LENGTH`. If not it is taken in by next scanning statements.

if, `#define POKEMON_LENGTH 15` then, always enter Pokemon name `14` or less characters as 15th space is for `\0`, and anything above that will invoke undefined behaviour...

---

I've made changes to your `addPokemon()` function : *(I've expalined in comments)*

```
void addPokemon(void)
{

    pokemonPtr firstPtr;
    pokemonPtr thisPokemon;
    firstPtr = NULL;

    firstPtr =(pokemon *) malloc(sizeof(pokemon));
    firstPtr->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

    printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
    fgets(firstPtr->name, POKEMON_LENGTH, stdin);

    printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf(" %d",&firstPtr->number);  //give a space to consume \n

    firstPtr->next =(pokemon *) malloc(sizeof(pokemon));

    thisPokemon = firstPtr->next;

    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10)
    {

        thisPokemon->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

        printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
        scanf(" ");//consume white spaces or \n
        fgets(thisPokemon->name, POKEMON_LENGTH, stdin);
        printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
        scanf(" %d",&thisPokemon->number);

        thisPokemon->next =(pokemon *) malloc (sizeof(pokemon));
        thisPokemon = thisPokemon->next;

        i++;

        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally,

> **Why to give a space?**
>
> By giving a space,the compiler consumes the `'\n'` character or any other white space (`'\0'`,`'\t'` or `' '` ) from the previous `scanf()`

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies i hope this takes away your problems... I've run the code and it works as expected

Comment: oh nice, thx for the additional input. For now the scanf solution above does the trick for now. As soon as I start experimenting saving information into files I need to come back to using "fgets".

Can you recommend any literature on "consuming white space"? I mean I totally start to get what you guys mean, but I don't really understand the causality to this rules.

I wish I could give you both the check, or at least "the answer is useful" (i have not enough reputation yet).

cheers